# How can I solve aws load balancer 502 error?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

Now, I am trying to solve ELB 502 error.
I am using express node js server and deploy server with ECS, deployment type `instance`.

And ELB keeps export 502 errors.

As I check elb access log, lots of logs contains

```
request_processing_time, target_processing_time >= 0

response_processing_time = -1
```

I found some documentations that this occurs when server's `keepAliveTimeout` is shorter than ALB's `idle timeout`.
However, I set server's timeout 65 secounds as

```
app.js
server.keepAliveTimeout = 65000;
server.headersTimeout = 66000;
```

and ELB idle timeout is 60 seconds.

What would be the problem then?

Comment: What is the health status of instances associated with LB?

Comment: health state is always healthy, no health states changed

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurred because your connection is closed and thus AWS throws 502 (gateway error).

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end('Hello World!');
});

server.keepAliveTimeout = 60 * 1000; // Set keep-alive timeout to 60 seconds

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 8080');
});
```

In this example, the keepAliveTimeout is set to 60 seconds (60,000 milliseconds), which should be long enough to match the idle timeout of most ALBs. You can adjust this value as needed based on the idle timeout setting of your ALB.

After making this change, you'll need to restart your Node.js application for the changes to take effect.

NOTE: Also check if your target is health based on your configuration.

Comment: As I mentioned, I set server's keepAliveTimeout 65 seconds when alb's idle timeout is 60 seconds like ```server.keepAliveTimeout = 65000;``` But still happens. What can I do?